# Don't have Back button when startActivity (Android)

Tags: android-activity

I'm a new Android dev. I read this article http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

When startActivity everythings is oke, message display perfect, but in menu bar does not have back button.

Anyone have any idea?
Thanks,

Maybe I missing "android:parentActivityName" in AndroidManifest.xml. Let's me try.

Answer (score 0):

Oke, founded. I missing `android:parentActivityName` property for new activity in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:parentActivityName="<name of previous activity>" >
</activity>
```